# ElasticSearch query too big

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query that seems to cause ElasticSearch to return a 504 “Request failed to get to the server (status code: 504)“. It seems to be due to the query size because if I pull out some of the params it will work.

I'm attempting to return matching data for multiple locations (could be hundreds) over multiple days (up to 21 days). Each location needs to look at certain time frames. Below is just a small sample of the larger query, but is essentially the same thing just with a lot more locations.

Is there is a better way to write the query then how I currently have it which would not have the chance of running into being an extremely large query when I have a lot of locations?

```
{
"size": 10,
"sort": [{
    "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
    }
}],
"_source": ["name", "location", "@timestamp"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [{
                                    "geo_polygon": {
                                        "location": {
                                            "points": ["-14.0625,12.65625", "-15.46875,12.65625", "-15.46875,11.25", "-14.0625,11.25", "-14.0625,12.65625"]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }, {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [{
                                    "range": {
                                        "@timestamp": {
                                            "lte": 1537809912161,
                                            "format": "epoch_millis",
                                            "gte": 1537747200000
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }, {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [{
                                    "geo_polygon": {
                                        "location": {
                                            "points": ["60.46875,22.5", "59.0625,22.5", "59.0625,21.09375", "60.46875,21.09375", "60.46875,22.5"]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }, {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [{
                                    "range": {
                                        "@timestamp": {
                                            "lte": 1537808898616,
                                            "format": "epoch_millis",
                                            "gte": 1537747200000
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "range": {
                                        "@timestamp": {
                                            "lte": 1537721508544,
                                            "format": "epoch_millis",
                                            "gte": 1537660800000
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fresh versions big query is 400 error code. You can look for error in log

```
sudo tail -n 200 /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
sudo tail -n 200 /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log | grep maxClauseCount
```

if you have line

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
```

Then you have to big query and you need to increase `maxClauseCount`. For this add line

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000
```

to the file `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`